# Iterating in Scheme

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

Let's say that I have a list of lists in Scheme, like so:

```
 (define a-list  (list (list a b) (list c d) (list e f) (list g h) (list i j)))
```

How would I go about defining a function that would consume this list such that I could use another function to consume each letter in the list?

For instance, I had another function

```
(define (smorg a)
  (...))
```

So, how do I go about doing smorg a, smorg b, smorg c... ?

Comment: I'm very new to Scheme (and recursion at that). So far, I've tried bruteforce methods, i.e. smorg(first(first a-list)), smorg(second(first a-list)), etc. I'd just like to automate this process somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you understand what `list?`, `map`, `car` and `cdr` do. They might be of use.

Comment: now that I've covered it in class, map actually does seem like the more elegant solution.

Answer (score 6):

What textbook are you using?

If the answer is *How to Design Programs*, then follow the design recipe. In particular, you need a data definition; the data definition is used to generate a template, which tells you exactly how to get the recursion right.

If you're not using HtDP, I highly suggest you give it a read. The book is available online, here: http://www.htdp.org/. Then follow the design recipe. In particular, you need a data definition etc etc etc.

In either case, here's a hint: Never, *ever* use the `list` function before you've mastered recursion. Not in your functions, not even in your examples. It gets in your way. Build your lists with `cons` and `empty`.